# How can I display moving object in google maps api 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to show movement in a google maps just like in this example
http://www.labnol.org/internet/live-flight-tracking-google-maps/12308/

I am starting, and followed an example to load markers from mysql and put them in a map. But this is all static. If I keep track of a moving object in my database, how can I display them in real time?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `marker` is your Marker instance, you should use some Ajax call to get new coordinates, depending how you return them, lets say your script will return an Object of `lat` and `long` and assign it to variable `new_location`. Now you need to change marker position to new coordinates:

```
function change_pos(new_location) {
    var LatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(new_location.lat, new_location.long);
    marker.setPosition(LatLong);
}
```

Just call this function everytime you got replay from Ajax.

And thats it.